# Comment nomme-t-on le « eggcorn » en linguistique ?

Tags: vocabulaire, linguistique, lexique

Un « eggcorn » est « l'altération d'une phrase par le biais d'une mauvaise compréhension ou d'une réinterprétation d'un ou plusieurs de ses éléments, créant une nouvelle phrase ayant un sens différent de l'original mais qui a toujours un sens et est plausible lorsqu'elle est utilisée dans le même contexte » (trad. automatique de l'anglais sur Wikipedia, « [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) »).

Par exemple, *pre-fixed* pour « prix fixe » :

[image]
 <sub><sub>Modifié à partir d'une image sur Wikipédia provenant de desultrix sur Flickr (voir [ici](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Prefixed_menu.jpg), cc-by-sa-2.0)</sub></sub>

> - Dine in Brooklyn! 
>   Pre-fixed 3 course
>    Lunch and dinner 
>    ($20.11-$25)
> - A'la Carte Menu [sic]
> - Cappuccino & Dessert
> - Open until 11

Comment se nomme ce concept en linguistique ?

Answer (score 3):

On peut appeler ça un **barbarisme** ou une **impropriété**.

Le [Bescherelle](https://bescherelle.ca/fautes-courantes/) cite ***une tête d'oreiller*** pour « taie d'oreiller » comme barbarisme et ***en tout et partout*** pour « en tout et pour tout » comme impropriété.

Quand la faute prête à sourire, on peut aussi l'appeler ***une perle***:

[Larousse:](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/perle/59654)

> 6. Familier. Erreur, méprise ou maladresse grossière qu'on relève dans les propos ou les écrits de quelqu'un.
>    Synonymes :
>
>    bévue - bourde (familier)

Je comprends ce ***pre fixed*** comme une innovation sémantique distincte de *prefixed* (prefixe au sens grammatical) mais signifiant « **fixé avant** », c'est à dire : ce groupe de trois items a été préalablement défini et n'est pas modifiable. On pourrait le comparer à *pre-cooked* ou a *predefined*.

C'est aussi une réinterprétation de ***[prix fixe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_d%27h%C3%B4te)*** à la phonétique similaire, qui est rarement utilisé dans ce contexte en France (on dit simplement *menu* par opposition à *à la carte*).

Comment: Est-ce que ta réponse passe le test des [_phémonènes similaires_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn#Similar_phenomena) de l'article ?

Comment: Pas forcément si une spécificité de l'eggcorn est que son auteur fait preuve de créativité et de logique.

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce cas, c'est un anglicisme ou du franglais au lieu d'un *eggcorn* des deux langues; c'est peut-être une *mondegreen*, pas forcément, plutôt un abus de langage imprévu.  Le sens reste; ce n'est pas un jeu de mots hors des grammaires bilingues. Où se trouve le préfixe ?  Il y en a trois ?

C'est probablement une [coquille](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coquille/19202). C'est une faute d'orthographe qui ne change pas le sens pour beaucoup de monde mais c'est quand même la base de ce genre d'hyponymes. Dans l'exemple il s'agit de la morphologie anglaise là où la terminaison en anglais est utisée sans vouloir changer le sens attendu, ni de créer d'un jeux de mots.  Moi qui me dis parfois en anglais "I'm bouleversed by this," j'applique une règle générale de la mauvaise langue.  On peut parler de code switching.

> La définition de
> [eggcorn](https://www.educalingo.com/fr/dic-en/eggcorn/amp) dans le dictionnaire est un malapropisme ou
> une faute d'orthographe découlant de la similitude entre le son du mot
> mal orthographié ou mal utilisé et celui correct dans l'accent de la
> personne qui fait l'erreur.
>
> La nouvelle phrase introduit un sens qui est différent de l'original,
> mais plausible dans le même contexte, comme «la maladie de l'ancien
> temps» pour «la maladie d'Alzheimer». Ceci est contraire à un
> malapropisme, où la substitution crée une phrase absurde.

Donc l'exemple pourrait se prendre pour un *eggcorn* *en anglais* et à la fois l'*eggcorn* en question ne fait-il pas partie de la catégorie de malapropisme ?  On peut toujours comprendre.  Enfin l'affixe est un suffixe et **que** dans le domaine d'une carte de menu chez les grammaires bilingues on peut s'en amuser, ce qui fait une malapropisme, [abus de langage](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/abus_de_langage) avec un effet comique involontaire.  Enfin dans ce cas et afin de répondre à la question, on dit *eggcorn*.  Parfois on dit *mondegreen* mais c'est un *eggcorn*.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ceux qui écrivent ***pre fixed*** ont la notion de préfixe grammatical en tête. Il s'agit pour moi plutôt d'une association de *pre* (avant) et *fixed* (non modifiable). Le choix présenté sur la tableau a été **pré**défini et il est "**fixé**" (figé).

Comment: Bien oui, il s'agit d'une table d'hôte prix fixe.  Je trouve assez drôle quand même.  Merci comme d'hab :)

Comment: Bizarre d'appeler ça une "table d'hôte" alors qu'on est dans le contexte d'un hotel ou d'un restaurant. En France, une table d'hôte, c'est quand un particulier qui loue des chambres **chez lui** (B&B) propose aussi des repas aux personnes hébergées.

Comment: C'est un emprunt trop utilisé.  Il faut faire *fancy à la mode* et l'anglais cherche toujours comment faire comme en français depuis le 17è siècle ou bien auparavant même si c'est à l'auberge.

Comment: C'est pas par contre la table d'honneur d'un mariage.